# Solution to a functional equation

Tags: number-theory, inequality, summation, functional-equations

Let $n,i$ be positive integers and $C$ a strictly positive real value.
Consider the equation for $f$ :
$$1*\ln(f(n)) = C * \sum_{3<i* \ln(i) < \sqrt{n}} \left(\ln[f( i* \ln(i) )-1)] - \ln[(f( i* \ln(i) )-1) - 2 f( i* \ln(i) ) *i* \ln(i)] \right)$$

Where $*$ means multiply and round off with the [floor function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aFloor_function.svg).
The order for $*$ is from left to right.

Does this equation for $f(n)$ have any solution for a given $C$ such that $f(n)\ll n$ for sufficiently large $n$ ?

Comment: As defined, $*$ is not associative. What is the meaning of $*$ after "C" and what is the order of multiplication among the last two $*$?

Comment: $*$ is from left to right. Brackets have priority of course.
I make a small edit.

Comment: About the title. I like the edit taking out the actual equation. But the reason I did that was to avoid confusion with other posts of me (or other ppl) ; because im into functional equations ... Dilemma feelings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in current form, the equation doesn't have any solution beyond $n=25$.

Notice $i*\log(i) = 0, 1, 3, 5, 8, \ldots$ for $i = 1, 2, \ldots$

For $n \le 25$, there is no $i$ that satisfy $3 < i*\log(i) < \sqrt{n}$, we have:

$$1 * \log f(n) = 0 \implies 0 \le \log f(n) < 1 \implies 1 \le f(n) < e$$

For $25 < n \le 64$, the only $i$ that satisfy $3 < i*\log(i) < \sqrt{n}$ is $4$, we have:

$$1 * \log f(n) = C * \left(\log[f(5)-1] - \log[(f(5)-1) - 2 f(5)*4*\log(4)] \right)\tag{*}$$
Since $1 \le f(5) < e$, the argument in last $\log$ of $(*)$ becomes negative!

$$(f(5)-1) - 2 f(5)*5*\log(5) < e - 1 - 2 ( 1*4*\log(4)) = e - 11 < 0$$